# How to delete array in text file PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have a text file. I want to delete some lines with a query of search.
The array is line by line. I want to made it like http://keywordshitter.com/

The logic is,

SEARCH --> IN ARRAY --> OUTPUT IS ARRAY WITHOUT "QUERY OF SEARCH"

Code I have tried:

```
$fileset = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$line = explode("\n", $fileset);
$content = array_search("query",$line);
print_r($content);
```

MY file.txt

```
one
two
three
apple
map
```

I have used `array_search` but not working.

Comment: show us hat you have tried

Comment: I have update with my code. it's just code for search. but the output is empty

Comment: Can you post a sample bit of `file.txt` so we can reproduce issue?

Comment: Does `file.txt` have `query`? If so than this works, if not than that is your issue. https://eval.in/476069

Comment: that just a example, yes it have query in my text file.

Comment: See updated comment. Code works here/there. Seems to work in older/newer versions as well. https://3v4l.org/D7ZgU

Comment: I not use array just (a,b,c,d) but I use key and value like array([0]=>one [1]=>two)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do search like

```
$fileset=file("file.txt");   // file function reads entire file into an array
$len=count($fileset);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
  {
       if($fileset[$i]=="query")
          {
               $fileset[$i]="";
               break;                 //then we will stop searching
          }
   }
$fileset_improve=implode($fileset);    //this will again implode your file
$handle=fopen("file.txt","w");        //opening your file in write mode
fwrite($handle,$fileset_improve);     //writing file with improved lines
fclose($handle);                    //closing the opened file
```

remember this lines will make your search line `blank`....

if you wanna then you can arrange whole array i.e. `shifting following indexed data to previous index` to decrease line counts but this will increase your programming complexity.

Hope this will work for you.

Thanks

Comment: i will try it. hope it what i want.

Comment: Hi Abbas, i have try it. but I have problem. When I run script, Script just deleted the last of array query. What is your solution?

Comment: yeah, i didn't understand it too. I feel my list of array is not good. I feel there is a (space) in last of array. So when i search "query" there isn't array will select. but if i search "query " (with space) there is array selected. I confuse.

Comment: ok so you want to say in your file  `query`    is stored like this   `query    `    ??? we can do one thing...

use like   `if(trim($fileset[$i])=="$query")`

Comment: yes, like that. but i'm not sure, I have try and try. but not result anything. I want to delete the similar array too.

Comment: yes then try the above one i.e. `trim()`    to delete such strings also that contain whitespace on their ends...

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) on your explode function instead of "\n". PHP_EOL will handle the correct line break character(s) of the server platform.